# Scoping issues with nested scriptblocks and try ... finally

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, raii

I'm trying to implement [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)-style resource managing in PowerShell. What struck me as a good idea was to acquire the resource in a try-block and release it again in a finally-block (as it is guaranteed that the finally-block is executed). Sometimes, my resources depend on each other, so I use a nested approach. The outline is as follows:

My resource 1 is acquired like so (sorry for the lenghty code, could not find a way to shorten it):

```
function withResource1 {
    param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][scriptblock]$action )

    try {
        write-host "acquire resource1"

        <# ... compute resource 1... #>
        $resource1 = "<this is the resource>"

        invoke-command -scriptBlock $action -args $resource1
    } finally {
        write-host "release resource1"
        <# ... #>
    }
}
```

Resource 2 depends upon 1, so I acquire it like this:

```
function withResource2 {
    param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][scriptblock]$action )

    withResource1 { param( $res1 )
        try {
            write-host "acquire resource2"

            <# ... compute resource2, using resource1 ... #>
            $resource2 = "<and this is the other resource>"

            invoke-command -scriptBlock $action -args $resource2
        } finally {
            write-host "release resource2"
            <# ...  #>
        }
    }
}
```

Now (at least I was thinking), I could use resource 2 like this:

```
withResource2 { param( $res2 )
    write-host "I'm happy to have '$res2', which depends on resource 1"
}
```

I expected the output to be

```
acquire resource1
acquire resource2
I'm happy to have '<and this is the other resource>', which depends on resource 1
release resource2
release resource1
```

But what actually happened was some kind of infinite loop. The problem seems to be some kind of scoping issue, because if I rename `action` to, say `ac` in `withResource2`, then everything works as expected.

How can I achieve what I want? And is there a better way to simulate RAII in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out myself.

Inside the `try`-block within `withResource2`, there is no `$action` variable in scope 0, i.e.

```
get-variable -name action -scope 0
```

cannot find a variable named `action`. So it relents to `scope 1`, which is the parent scope (the scope of `withResource1`) and the `$action` there is precisely the scriptblock I'm supplying to `withResource1`. Calling it leads to an infinite loop.

What I actually wanted to call in the `try`-block in `withResource2` is the `$action` in `withResource2`, which is **2** scopes above. So changing the `invoke-command`-line in `withResource2` to

```
invoke-command -scriptBlock ( get-variable -name action -scope 2 ).Value -args $resource2
```

does the trick.

Comment: Could you get around this by naming it something other than `action`?  Maybe `action1` and `action2`.